Need suggestions for creating a standalone Windows desktop application
In my office I had been give a task to develop a simple billing desktop application which will have a button on admins side which on click send the data to the server for it I created an API and it's working.
I've tried making this app using .net & Python but neither of those applications are working on Windows 7 they have worked on Windows 8 8.1 10 & 11 but when executing it on Windows 7 it is giving errors like .net framework is not installed or this application is not executable & when I try to install those things on windows 7 they don't get installed...
Up to my knowledge I've tried everything to make it work on 7 but it is not working...
My question is are there any Desktop App builder with database (not SQL or MySQL just let me store the data in that app) out there on the web free which will help me generate this app so that it can work on all of the Windows os?
I know it may sound childish or ignorant but nothing is working. Gemini or GPT are suggesting only Python or .net but as previously told they are not working. How can I finish this baka app as soon as possible?
Edit
Project with using Python with Tkinter => 1).
Project with using .Net => 1).
2).
3).
5).
6).
7).
Edit
Now I'm trying to make this app using Java as I know this will work for sure in Windows 7 but when I'm stuck in the beginning phase of it when I'm running my dbconnect.java file I'm getting this error in the console => 1st

If you are using .NET then you must use the same, or later, version of the framework on each machine. So you need to check which is the latest version that is availalble for Windows 7 and build your application against that.

@OldBoy well that is not the problem the problem is the clients system is so low level that it can not even install the required framework this has to be an offline software with one button which when connected with net on click sends the data to the database in the server....
hope this cleared some of your doubts...

or maybe helped you understand my problem more clearly...

Sorry, I do not understand what youe mean.

@OldBoy Look I'm trying to develop an Windows Desktop App which will hold data inside of it and will act as an Stand Alone Application the Main Focus is that is should work on Windows 7 and later on versions but it is not working on windows 7.
I've made the app using Python & .Net but they are not working (Check the Edited Post for Images Please.)
I was asking for any option which will let me build the Desktop app and let me export the exe file of it.
Hope now you get what I'm trying to say.

If you cannot install any .NET framework on the Windows 7 system, the  you cannot use any .NET components in your application. You will need to find a language and set of components that will work on the lowest leve system first.

@OldBoy I'm trying to make this app using Java but it is a little bothersome because it is not getting configured correctly...

If you want people to help you then you will need to provide some proper details. We cannot guess what you are doing in Java, or what you mean by "it is not getting configured correctly".

@OldBoy when I run the dbconnect.java file it is saying this => SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
the configuration problem is this. I've not been able to setup the java project correctly that's why this error is being shown I guess.

Sorry, I know nothing about SLF4J, but the message suggests that it is looking for some associated library. Follow the link in the message for more information.

You can use electron.js or python with tkinter

I'm not sure if I'm understanding what you want, but you can use ttk.Notebook to use tabs in your tkinter.
`root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Ejemplo de pestañas con Tkinter")
Create notebook
notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
Create frames for notebooks
tab1 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
tab3 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
Add tabs to notebook
notebook.add(tab1, text='tab 1')
notebook.add(tab2, text='tab 2')
notebook.add(tab3, text='tab 3')`
